# DataTemplateSelector item is Null

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplateselector

This is similar issue to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490292/item-is-null-in-datatemplateselector), but the answer did not work for me.
 
I have a simple window with a ContentControl. I wanted to use a template selector with it. 
I set up the binding for the `Content` and chose a `ContentTemplateSelector` (which is located in another file/namespace).

```
<Window x:Class="EpicNum.View.Floaters.FloaterDnD"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="57" Width="130"  
    WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False">

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource NodeTemplateSelector}"
                    />
</Window>
```

My template selector class looks looks like this:

```
class NodeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement UIElement = container as FrameworkElement;

        // Add new information for new Node Template selections here...
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(ViewModel.NodeAdder))
        {
            return UIElement.FindResource("TemplateAdderNode") as DataTemplate;
        }
        else if (item.GetType() == typeof(ViewModel.NodeText))
        {
            return UIElement.FindResource("TemplateTextNode") as DataTemplate;
        }
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

Somewhere in the ViewModel, I create a new instance for this window and set the DataContext

```
FloaterDnD F = new FloaterDnD();
F.DataContext = sourceItem;
F.Show();
```

Now, for some reason the `item` in my template selector turns out `null`. I can't figure out, what am I missing.

At runtime, in code I can see that the DataContext is set correctly
[image]

But, when it gets to the template selector, it's `null`
[image]

Might be related. 
 For some reason, when I set the `ContentTemplateSelector` in xaml for the window, the UI designer shows an error:
[image]

 
 If I remove the assignment for `ContentTemplateSelector`, then the error is gone and it shows the window as normal.

Comment: It seems odd to use a DataTemplateSelector in the first place. Why don't you declare automatically selected DataTemplates, i.e. without an `x:Key` but with their `DataType` set to either NodeAdder or NodeText?

Comment: Good question. I guess, it's because, initially there was only one `Type` with an Enum that stored information about the "type". Template selector was used to check that enum for each item. After some changes, some things were simplified, but this was left as it is.